# ADF - Pick up values from JSON array to use it as variable

Tags: azure-data-factory

What I want to do?

Step one: I want to pick up all values of users (ID) from JSON file and put them together in a list.

Step two: Use ID's in a variable like [https://microsoft.com/API/threads_createdby="&ID&"](https://microsoft.com/API/threads_createdby=%22&ID&%22) to retrieve all threads created by User1, User2, User3 and so on.

Now I'm importing JSON file with Lookup (Dataset) see below:

`{ "count": 1, "value": [ { "result": [ { "user": { "display_value": "User1", "link": "https://microsoft.com", "value": "4356yrtge43t5gre" } }, { "user": { "display_value": "User2", "link": "https://microsoft.com", "value": "fdgtrh5t4rewfr54" } }, { "user": { "display_value": "User3", "link": "https://microsoft.com", "value": "rgethyj7u6y5terf" } } ] } ], "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "server343", "billingReference": { "activityType": "PipelineActivity", "billableDuration": [ { "meterType": "SelfhostedIR", "duration": 0.016666666666666666, "unit": "Hours" } ] }, "durationInQueue": { "integrationRuntimeQueue": 1 } }`

Next step is Foreach with Append Variable (@activity('JSONImport').output.value & @item().result and I can see all ID's together with this error message `of type 'Array' cannot be appended to the variable 'Value' of type 'Array'. The action type 'AppendToArrayVariable' only supports values of types 'Float, Integer, String, Boolean, Object'.`

With @item().result[0].user.value I see this: `{ "variableName": "Value", "value": "4356yrtge43t5gre" }`

What I'am doing wrong?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I tried the same expression that you have given in Foreach and append I ended up with same error.

[image]

The above error occured because when you look at the **lookup activity output array value is an array** and **`result` is also an array**.  The error states that appending array to an array is not supported. So, the error came because you tried to append an array(`result`) to another.

> Step two: Use ID's in a variable like [https://microsoft.com/API/threads_createdby="&ID&"](https://microsoft.com/API/threads_createdby=%22&ID&%22) to retrieve all threads created by User1, User2, User3 and so on.

The `result` array is at the `0th` index of the lookup output array. So, to achieve your requirement give the result array to Foreach and use append activity inside it.

`@activity('Lookup1').output.value[0].result`

In append, for sample I have given the below dynamic content(To domonstrate accessing `value` key).

`https://microsoft.com/API/thread_createdby=@{item().user.value}`

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

If you want to store the result array in an array variable, you can directly use the same `@activity('Lookup1').output.value[0].result` in a set variable activity and use as per your requirement.

Comment: Hi @Rakesh Govindula this worked like a charm Thank you very much. Only thing left here is how to pick up all append variables and run each query to save data in SQLDB with copy data?

Comment: If you want to copy each row(`https://microsoft.com/API/threads_createdby=%22&ID&%22`) to a SQL table, then inside ForEach use a set variable activity(String variable) with same dynamic content as append. After this use a script activity with insert into table command and values as this variable. If you want use only a copy activity, I think it's better to raise a new question regarding your ask, so that the community may assist you.